# Removing wires from a circuit board socket

Tags: pcb, wiring

I'm trying my hand at repairing old joysticks. I have this Dualshock Analog Controller (SCPH-1200 M) which came with my old PSX and it didn't work properly anymore. So I've decided to open it so I could repair it or at least learn something new in the process. I've examined the connections from the PSX to the joystick and they've all seemed fine, correct voltage and no short-circuits. When I plugged it I've found that it seems as there were some problems with the wires because if I held the josytick in some way, it would turn off. So I've concluded that the problem must be in a strangled section of the wire, so I've cut that section to later rejoin the cables. However it appears as I cut the wires coming from the circuit board too short and I cannot make a connection with the other side. [image: Wires coming from the circuit board]

So my next idea was to remove those wires still attached to the circuit board and insert the other side directly into the holes of the white socket (I don't know its name). But I cannot seem to get the wires out - I've tried pulling them but they won't budge and I don't want to break any more stuff.

Do you know how can I remove these wires in a way that will allow me to insert new ones into them?

Comment: That's not a socket. It's a plastic frame to hold crimped leads for soldering to the board. You'll need to unsolder each pin and remove the frame+leads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing the other side, I am fairly confident that the wires have been soldered to the pcb on the other side. To remove them, you would have to desolder it. Use a clean soldering iron on the other side and pliers on the cut wire side and pull after heating it up, one by one. The plastic can be removed when all the wires are out. Clean the holes like you would any desoldered joint and you'll be ready to add new wires.

Answer (score 1):

As Passerby has written, it looks like the crimp terminals are soldered to the board.  If de-soldering them is easy then I would do that, but you might find that the terminals have tangs that clip them to the board and/or the housing, in which case de-soldering and removal would be tricky.

Alternatives would be (in order of my preference):

1) Tack your new connections to the pins on the reverse of the board, thus: Strip and tin the wire. Use pointed-nose pliers and cutters to form a small J on the end of the wire about 2.5 mm long, tack the J to the pin.

2) Carefully strip the trimmed wires, splice on your new connection and insulate with heat-shink sleeving.

Comment: In that case, OP could use some clippers and cut away the wires and plastic before desoldering.